# Running a script in terminal using Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Im trying to run this script in the terminal but its not working and says permission denied. scriptEmail is filename.

```
% find . -type d -exec ./scriptEmail {} \;
```

`scriptEmail` is written as follows:

```
# !/bin/bash
# Mail Script
find gang-l -type f -name "*" -exec sh -c ' file = "$0" java RemoveHeaders "$file" > processed/$file ' {} ';'
```

My read write permission

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

Comment: What error are you getting from it?

Comment: Permission is denied

Comment: And is it actually an executable file? Can you run `./scriptEmail .` successfully, for instance? Does `ls -l` show it having executable permissions? Does it have a valid shebang?

Comment: By the way, if you don't want `find` to try to run it against `.`, but only against subdirectories, you'll want to use `-mindepth 1`.

Comment: can you show `ls -l` of scriptEmail?

Comment: `# !/bin/bash
# Mail Script

find gang-l -type f -name "*" -exec sh -c '
file = "$0"
java RemoveHeaders "$file" > processed/$file
'
{} ';'` This is my script

Comment: This question is so vague, by the way, that it's not possible to find a good duplicate to close it as -- some of them have actually verified file permissions to be correct but are stimied by a `noexec`-flagged filesystem, SELinux, or similar. Here, there's just no details to run on.

Comment: @ryhan112, `# !` is wrong; it needs to be `#!`, no spaces.

Comment: @ryhan112, ...also, edit that into the question rather than leaving it as a comment. Also, show your file permissions.

Comment: BTW, you realize you're going to get a ton of files processed more than once, because _both_ `find` instances are recursing?

Comment: Well it keeps on giving the permission denied thing, no idea, i have also tried this `
% ./scriptEmail.sh
` but i still get permission denied

Comment: @ryhan112 You must show the actual commands executed and the actual output of the commands.  If any of the commands are your own scripts, show the source for those.  Show the _complete_ output of the commands, not just part of the line,  '-rwxr-xr-x' is not enough.  Do that and you'll usually get a better answer quicker, otherwise, it's like shooting in the dark.

Comment: @ryhan112, as I told you two hours ago (an hour before your last comment), use `sh scriptEmail.sh` (or, if it's a bash script rather than a POSIX sh script, `bash scriptEmail.sh`) -- and ideally, rename it to no longer use the inaccurate `.sh` extension. If you don't have the ability to create genuinely executable files, you can't create genuinely executable files, but that doesn't mean you can't run them through an appropriate interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for permissions:

- Check that your shebang is at the very top of your file, and that it starts *exactly* with `#!`; `# !` **will not work**.
- Check that your files are given execute permissions; `chmod 750 scriptEmail` will do.
- Check that your file uses UNIX newlines -- with DOS newlines, your shebang may have a hidden character making it point to an interpreter which doesn't actually exist.
- Check that the directory your file is stored in is in a directory where executable scripts are allowed (not mounted with the `noexec` flag, or in a SELinux context disallowing execution).

If your mount point is `noexec` or your ability to create executable scripts is blocked by SELinux or similar, then use `find . -type d -exec bash ./scriptEmail {} \;` to explicitly specify an interpreter rather than attempting to execute your script.

---

Second: Since you're executing your script with `find` already -- and using that to recurse through directories -- you don't need a second `find` inside (which would have you potentially operating on `processed/dirA/dirB/file` as well as `processed/dirB/file` and `processed/file` -- with errors for all of these where the directory doesn't exist).

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$1" || exit             # if we can't cd to directory given in argument, exit.
mkdir -p processed || exit  # if we can't create our output directory, exit.
for f in *; do              # ...iterate through all directory contents...
  [ -f "$f" ] || continue   # ...if they aren't files, skip them...
  java RemoveHeaders "$f" >processed/"$f" # run the processing for one item
done
```

Comment: I have ran your formatted script and im still getting permission denied

Comment: Did you go through the checklist? I gave you four bullets; they all matter.

Comment: (If your sysadmins don't want contents of home directories to be executable, they can do that, and there's not much you can do about it; I also added notes about a workaround).

Comment: `chmod 750 scriptEmail` This now works so should i run the code again and check if it runs the script?

Comment: If what you're dealing with is a `noexec` mount flag, then chmod won't help -- you'll have the permission on the inode but it still will refuse to execute. If all that was wrong was individual file permissions, then you may be good to go. In any event -- yes, absolutely, test! Why do you need permission from me to experiment? :)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
sudo find . -type d -exec ./scriptEmail {} \;
```

Comment: Im using a university server to access the files therefore this file isnt 'sudoable'

Comment: @ryhan112, ...even if you did have the permission to use `sudo`, it still would be more likely to break things (ie. by creating files your regular user couldn't write to) than to fix them properly without side effects in this scenario.